# How to get a First() without raising an exception if it doesn't exist? [When FirstOrDefault doesn't help]

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, linq-to-sql

I want to get a `First` using Linq2Sql without raising an exception in case no result was found.

I know of `FirstOrDefault`, but then if I receive a default I don't know if it was in the database or if it was returned as the `OrDefault`.

Is there a way to get a `First` without raising an exception but ***with*** knowing whether or not the received value is from the database?

I know I can check `Any()` first, but that means accessing the database twice. I'd like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: Use `Any()` to see if there is a result or not.

Comment: @juergend I'm willing to ignore that race condition, but that means accessing the database twice. I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your problem occurs because you're projecting a nullable column, and you cannot distinguish between `FirstOrDefault()` returning null because the field was null versus because the record was not found:

```
var lastName = persons
    .Where(p => p.FirstName == 'xxx')
    .Select(p => p.LastName)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

A simple fix would be to project your column into an anonymous type:

```
var record = persons
    .Where(p => p.FirstName == 'xxx')
    .Select(p => new { p.LastName })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

This way, if `record` itself is null, then it means that no record was found. However, if `record` is not null but `record.LastName` is null, then the record was found with a field value of `null`.

Comment: This sounds like a good workaround (+1). But I'll wait some time not accepting yet -  perhaps there's a built in way to do it. Isn't this somethings that is not infrequent? I'd expect there to be demand for something like this.

Comment: It is something I've encountered several times, but I've generally relied on the above workaround, since the semantics of the resulting `record` match what one would intuitively expect (no record versus record containing null value). You're welcome to keep the question open in case there are conciser solutions.